# I can't find my OSQA install directory in OpenShift via ssh

Tags: installation, openshift, osqa

I have a basic understanding of navigating via SSH.  I have installed OSQA following the instructions here:
     https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/OSQA-openshift-quickstart
The installation worked, and I can access and modify my OSQA settings via the admin web interface with no problems.

I need to edit the settings_local.py file to disable OpenID (and a few other things), but when I ssh into my app through rhc, I can't find any of the directories I think I'm supposed to be looking for.  Here is what I see when I ls:

```
app-deployments  app-root  git  mysql  python
```

And that's it!

I know I must be doing something wrong, but I've been searching all over, and most instructions start with "navigate to the OSQA installation directory - cd OSQA" -- which seems not to exist!  I get the same list of directories when I SFTP in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking in ~/app-root/repo or ~/app-root/repo/wsgi

Comment: ~app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/osqa    
Thank you!